# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Login Screen Crashes

Tags: login, crash, lts, 20.04

2 Days ago I Upgraded from 18 to 20.04 LTS. Till today every thing was working, though after setting up the flutter variables and restarting the Laptop a problem started occurring. Whenever I try to Login after pressing Enter the Screen flip backs to the Accounts Window. I tried to restart but the problem persist. I have all my college work over the Ubuntu System. So need help! How can i troubleshoot it.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by disabling automatic log in. Boot from your installation media, mount the root partition, and from [these instructions](https://vitux.com/how-to-enable-disable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/), follow the command line steps.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded yesterday from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 19.10 and then to 20.04 LTS.

And I faced the exact same issue. On the login screen I would select my user and enter my password, and the screen would blank and after a couple of seconds, I was back at the login screen.

It seems it is a [bug in xorg](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1861609).

Till they fix it, what you can do is (and what I did was):

1. Press `CTRL + ALT + F1`
2. This will bring you to a text-login. Enter your credentials and login should work.
3. Then install openbox by "sudo apt install openbox".
4. Then reboot the computer.
5. On arriving at the login screen, after the reboot, look for an icon on the screen, which would let you change your "Window Manager" from "Ubuntu" or "Gnome" or whatever you are using, to "Openbox".
6. Login to Openbox and you have a GUI environment, at least.

I cannot explain, why it does not crash for Openbox. In any case, you can recover your work/data from the system either by logging in to the text mode either by pressing `CTRL-ALT-F1` and then using the commandline to transfer your data out or you can use Openbox.

p.s. strangely, they say that the bug is more prevalent on VMs. I have it the other way round. On the VM, Ubuntu 20.04, runs absolutely smoothly (though be it, it was a fresh install). But on bare-metal it has these crashes (could be due to the buggy upgrade).

**EDIT:**
On a side note, if in any case this does not work for you, just maybe it is because we are using different "Display Managers". So, just to test (in case the previous steps failed), from the text-login, you can access using `CTRL+ALT+F1`, install lightdm `sudo apt install lightdm` and when the configuration screen pops up, choose lightdm. Reboot and try to login with the Openbox window manager again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on login after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.  It kept returning me to the login screen and "dmesg | tail" didn't indicate anything.  So I rebooted in recovery mode, logged in as root, installed lightdm and now it works.

To note: I have 3 monitors on an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 card.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the enter key before entering the password (with an empty input field) and only then enter the password.

Comment: This answer is based on personal experience of using Ubuntu for a long time. I am using Ubuntu on a tablet with a touch screen, with the ability to attach a keyboard with a touchpad to the device. In addition, my device has 4 GB of RAM on board and the ability to change the orientation of the screen by rotating the device. On my device, all sorts of buffer overflow options are very noticeable, which also affect the update of the software system processes. Sometimes I have to press the enter key before the password is entered to continue. I do not speak English.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the same, but Pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1` didn't do nothing. But pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F3` changed screen to full screen console mode and I had to logging in by typing my username and password. I didn't want to install `openbox`, because I didn't know what it will do, so decided to try and update everything by typing `sudo apt get update` and `sudo apt get upgrade`, found some updates, Pressing `Y` started upgrading. After that I needed to reboot, so typing `sudo reboot now` did the trick.
And I was able to login again. Hopes this will be helpful to someone.